# Counting points on the unit circle with coordinates in a ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $ O_d $ be the ring of integers of the totally real field $ K_d:=\mathbb{Q}(cos(2 \pi/d)) $.

Question:

Are there finitely many $ x,y \in O_d $ such that
$$
x^2+y^2=1
$$
In other words, are there finitely many $ O_d $ points on the unit circle? Let $ n_d $ denote the number of points on the unit circle with coordinates from $ O_d $. Is $ n_d $ finite?

Context:

For $ d=1,2,3,4,6 $ we have $ n_1=n_2=n_3=n_4=n_6=4 $ since $ (\pm 1, 0),(0,\pm 1) $ are the only $ O_d $ points on the unit circle for $ d=1,2,3,4,6 $.   [Are there any other dyadic points on the unit circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488727/are-there-any-other-dyadic-points-on-the-unit-circle) seems relevant to determining $ n_8 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \in O_d$ be such that $x^2+y^2=1$.

Let $z=x+iy$: it’s an algebraic integer. For any automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{C}$, $|\sigma(z)|^2=|\sigma(x) \pm i \sigma(y)|^2=\sigma(x)^2+\sigma(y)^2=\sigma(x^2+y^2)=1$ (because $\sigma(x),\sigma(y) \in O_d \subset \mathbb{R}$).

Therefore, $z$ is a root of unity, which shows that $x,y$ are the real and imaginary parts of a root of unity – hence $n_d$ is finite.

Proof that $z$ is a root of unity: the minimal polynomials of the $z^n$ live in a finite set, so there is some $n \geq 2$ such that $z^n=\sigma(z)$ for some automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Then $z^{n^d}=\sigma^{d}(z)$ for all $d>0$. For some $d>0$, $\sigma^d(z)=1$, so $z^{n^d-1}=1$.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to count $ n_d $? For example for $ d=5 $?

Comment: The couples $(x,y)$ are exactly those such that $x+iy$ is a root of unity – lying in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/5},i)=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/20})$. If such a root has its real and imaginary parts in $O_5$, then so does all of its powers. So the question is: which roots of unity does $K_5[i]$ contain? By the above, they’re clearly $20$-th roots of unity. But $e^{2i\pi/5} \notin K_5[i]$ (because this field has the same degree as, but is distinct from, $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/5})$). So only the fourth roots are possible, hence $n_5=4$. I think it’s the same for any odd $d$.

Comment: Is it possible that $ n_d $ is totally determined by the power of $ 2 $ that divides $ d $? So $ n_d=4 $ for all odd $ d $. $ n_d= 8 $ for all single even $ d $. And in general maybe $ n_d $ equals $ 4 $ times the largest power of $ 2 $ dividing $ d $?

Comment: For odd $d$, $K_{2d}=K_d$, so if $d$ is even and isn’t divisible by $4$, you would still have $n_d=4$. I’m expecting that $n_d=d$ when $4 \mid d$, because $K_d$ contains the real and imaginary parts of all the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/d})=K_d(i)$, and that this field contains the $d$-th roots of unity and no other root of unity.

Comment: I see so you expect that $ n_d=d $ if $ 4|d $ and otherwise $ n_d=4 $ which is consistent with $ n_d=4 $ for $d=1,2,3,4,5,6 $ and $ n_8=8 $